# how to validate credit cards using jquery.validation creditcard2?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I am looking to use [this plugin](http://www.ihwy.com/labs/jquery-validate-credit-card-extension.aspx) along with jquery.validation plugin in my forms but from what I see I would need to use a select tag in order for creditcard2 to function correctly.

What I currently have is this:

```
 <p class="ccType">
     <label for="card_type" class="error">You must select a credit card from one of the following.</label>
        <br>
     <input type="radio" value="1000" id="card_type_1000" name="card_type" style="outline:none; border:none;" /> 
        <img src="../visa.png" alt="Visa" width="50" height="30" align="top" /> 
        <input type="radio" value="1002" id="card_type_1002" name="card_type" style="outline:none; border:none;" /> 
        <img src="../mastercard.png" alt="Mastercard" width="50" height="30" align="top" /> 
        <input type="radio" value="1006" id="card_type_1006" name="card_type" style="outline:none; border:none;" /> 
        <img src="../discover.png" alt="Discover" width="50" height="30" align="top" /> 
        <input type="radio" value="1004" id="card_type_1004" name="card_type" style="outline:none; border:none;" /> 
        <img src="../amex.png" alt="American Express" width="50" height="30" align="top" />
    </p>
```

value = 1000 is "Visa"

value = 1002 is "MasterCard"

value = 1006 is "Discover"

value = 1004 is "AmEx"

The plugin site mentions creating a lookup hash. I don't know how to create one. Also the documentation that is on the site only shows examples using `<select></select>`. I am using inputs.

How can I get this to work with the set up that I currently have.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookup hash would look like

```
var hash = {
    1000: "Visa",
    1002: "MasterCard",
    1004: "AmEx",
    1006: "Discover"
};
```

Then you could use the following validation function, of course built into your current setup:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        cardnum: { // this should be the id of the card number field
            creditcard2: function(){ return hash[$('.ccType > input:checked').val()]; }
        }
    }       
});
```

This rather concise code first looks for all the `inputs` in your `.ccType` element. Then it selects the one that is checked (if any) and gets its value. Then the value is pushed through the hash to change it to a value the plugin likes. And... let's hope this works.

Comment: Yes... let me try this and get back to you. Thanks!